# Stemming, lemmatization in python

Tags: python, stemming, textblob

I have checked all the other trails and used few of the solutions. I am facing a challenge in using port stemmer. I am trying to eliminate the affixs however port stemmer reduces the words into some weird forms like languages becomes languag and strengthening becomes strengthn which is spelled incorrect.

I have to search the sentences using word for which I am using TextBlob. below is my code am using. I pulled the text from the link: http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html.
and I did a search for language using porterstemmer and wordnetlemmatizer. Wordnetlemma only reduces the plurals to singular values.

```
url = 'http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html'
a = urllib.urlopen(url)
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','Chrome')]
html = br.open(url).read()
raw = nltk.clean_html(html)
tokens = nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw)
t = [lmtzr.lemmatize(t) for t in tokens] 
text = nltk.Text(t)
sents = ' '.join([s.lower() for s in Text])
blob = TextBlob(sents)
matches = [str(s) for s in blob.sentences if search_words & set(s.words)]
```

Comment: Like the chapter you are linking to explains, this is what a stemmer does. It also explains that a lemmatizer does what it appears that you want instead, but it's not clear how you are dissatisfied with the WordNet lemmatizer. Are you saying it's not handling gerunds, past tense etc for you? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Also, as an aside, the Porter stemmer is named after its creator, Martin Porter. Its name doesn't directly have anything with ports or porting to do.

Comment: I am just going with the functionality. I need to search for the sentences using the keywords given, the stemmer is not doing the job as i stated. For e.g. i am looking for all sentences with word "
strengthen". Lemmatizer doesn't change the form and port stemmer is making it spell strengthn, missing an 'e'

Comment: "strengthening" is not a gerund its a verb form

Comment: That is intended. If you look for a word like "strengthen" you need to tokenize and stem the query, too!

Comment: That's what i figured last night. Also when i search and pull the sentences is there is a way i can also extract the one before and one after the sentences being extracted using the keyword??